# Euclid's unnecessary proof?

Tags: proof-verification, euclidean-geometry

Euclid I.18 proves the theorem —

> If two sides of a triangle are unequal, then the angle opposite the
>   greater side is greater than the angle opposite to the less.

The immediately next theorem to be proved is —

> If two angles of a triangle are unequal, then the side opposite the
>   greater angle is greater than the side opposite to the less.

But isn't that completely redundant? The former theorem states that **if and only if** a side is greater, the opposite angle will also be greater. So as corollary, if an angle is greater, most definitely its opposite side has to be greater or it wouldn't be greater in the first place.

Comment: The former theorem is *not* an if and only if. It is an **if** : **if** the sides are unequal, *then* the angle opposite the greater side is greater than the angle opposite to the less. When we prove this, we do not know *a priori* if the converse is true, which is the second yellow box : If the angles are unequal, so are the sides. To give an example : If you are in deep sleep, then you won't pick up a ringing telephone nearby, but if you don't pick up a ringing telephone nearby, it doesn't imply that you are in deep sleep. Like the above, this is not an if and only if.

Comment: Can you explain why you think the first theorem is an "if and only if"?  It certainly doesn't literally say "if and only if".